# Kendo Angular - update data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i have a problem. I am using kendo in my Angular web api and i have a problem with updating data. This is my code.

```
$scope.documentListGridOptions = {
    dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: serviceBase + "Documents/GetListDocuments",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                beforeSend: function (req)
                {
                    req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authGlobalService.getAuthorizationData().token);
                }
            },
            parameterMap: function (options)
            {
                if (options.filter)
                {
                    options.filter = options.filter.filters;
                }

                return JSON.stringify(options);
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "data",
            total: "total"
        },
        pageSize: 5,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverFiltering: true
    },
    selectable: 'row',
    scrollable: false,
    sortable: true,
    filterable: {
        extra: false
    },
    pageable: true,
    change: function (idSelectedVote)
    {
        $scope.$apply(function ()
        {
            $scope.setSelected(idSelectedVote.sender.dataItem(idSelectedVote.sender.select()));
        });
    },
    dataValueField: "id",
    columns: [{
        title: "Id dokumentu",
        field: "documentId",
        hidden: true
    },{
        title: "Nazwa dokumentu",
        field: "nameDocument"
    },{
        title: "Opis",
        field: "descriptionDocument"
    },{
        title: "Data dodania",
        field: "dateAdded"
    }]
};
```

Data are getting from database and all is fine. But when data will change i don't know how can i update my data. How can i make another request to database. Please for help.

edit:

```
var documentListGridOptionsRemote = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    autoSync: true,
    transport: {
        read: {
            method: 'POST',
            url: serviceBase + "Documents/GetListDocuments",
            data: { name: "eco" },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            beforeSend: function (req) {
                req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authGlobalService.getAuthorizationData().token);
            }
        },
        update: {
            method: 'POST',
            url: serviceBase + "Documents/GetListDocuments",
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function (req) {
                req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authGlobalService.getAuthorizationData().token);
            }
        }
    }
});

$scope.documentListGridOptions = {
    dataSource: documentListGridOptionsRemote,
    schema: {
        data: "data",
        total: "total"
    },
    selectable: "row",
    scrollable: false,
    sortable: true,
    filterable: {
        extra: false
    },
    pageable: true,
    columns: [
        { field: "documentId", title: "Id", hidden: true },
        { field: "nameDocument", title: "Nazwa dokumentu" },
        { field: "descriptionDocument", title: "Opis" },
        { field: "dateAdded", title: "Data dodania" },
        { field: "name", title: "Test" }

    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

in your dataSource's transport, you need to specify the update property like this:

```
transport: {
    read: {
        url: serviceBase + "Documents/GetListDocuments",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        beforeSend: function (req)
        {
            req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authGlobalService.getAuthorizationData().token);
        },
    update: {
            //you can have function for url if you need to customise you url
            //like url:function(data){ serviceBase + "Documents/GetListDocuments("+data.id+");} 
            url: serviceBase + "Documents/GetListDocuments",
            type: "POST",//properly dont need this one, as update is a 'PUT'
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            beforeSend: function (req)
            {
                req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authGlobalService.getAuthorizationData().token);
            }
        },
```

and use 'create' for add and 'destroy'
for the complete document, please check [this document](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource) , and also i will recommend to use angular httpProvider interceptor to handle the authentication token so you dont have to have beforeSend in every request

Comment: Thx for answer, I read this doc byt I can't use sync() or add() on documentListGridOptions. I make some like this but data from documentListGridOptionsRemote dont pass to documentListGridOptions. What am i  doing wrong? I edit my question.

Comment: @ŁukaszDramiskiRen do you have a insert and save function set up for your gird? if yes, you dont need to trigger sync() or add() function manually, there is more documents about the kendo grid [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline)

Comment: I haven't, my set up grid is in my first post. Sorry i am new in this framework. I studing this doc but is very confuse for me.